# Python: Traverse list from end to find first element satisfying a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, listiterator

I want to iterate over elements from the end of a list to find the index of the last occurrence of an element which contains a '}'.

Ideally, I want to maintain efficiency using iterators rather than actually reversing the whole list or searching for all occurrences that match this condition.

If I were finding the first occurrence, I would use:

```
next(i for i,x in enumerate(list) if '}' in x)
```

However, I tried something similar using reversed to create a reverse iterator, but this did not seem to work, presumably because enumerate doesn't handle iterators, or maybe I have misunderstood...

```
next(i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(list)) if '}' in x)
```

I am aware other ways of doing this would be:

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(list) if '}' in x][-1]
```

or:

```
next(i for i,x in enumerate(list[::-1]) if '}' in x)
```

However, I am looking for the most efficient way. I could of course write a loop for efficiency, but was wondering if there was a neat way of doing it using the functions available.

I am relatively new to Python so go easy on me, and let me know if I have misunderstood anything. I am using Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this list a list of characters?

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, don't use Python. Use C/C++/Java. Good luck!

Comment: Agreed, but lets go from the assumption that I have to use Python for legacy reasons.

Comment: what's wrong with your last solution? like @alfasin said, if you're **that** worried about efficiency python is not what you're looking for

Comment: enumerate should totally work for any random iterator...

Comment: @alfasin This is *not* a healthy attitude to take. Efficiency should be sought for in every language, as long as it doesn't detract from the core values of the language. There's no need to create the entire list to parse through if you have the `reversed` generator that does it faster.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose: Reversing via extended slicing is cool, but using the `reversed` iterator is more efficient, both in time & memory usage. Sure, it won't rival the speed of a compiled language, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: @Kupiakos maybe you're right. That said, I've seen so many questions about python/efficiency and it's a bit recidivous considering that any one of the 3 other languages I've mentioned above will be so much faster - a different magnitude... I'm not against doing thing more efficiently, but I don't think that it should be your main concern when you're writing Python code, and if it is - you're using the wrong tool, that's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

Your example

```
next(i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(lst)) if '}' in x)
```

works, but it returns the index of the *reversed* list. So if it finds the `'}'` in the last string of the (unreversed) list it will return 0.

So to get the index in the original, unreversed list you could do

```
len(lst) - 1 - next(i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(lst)) if '}' in x)
```

---

The above code raises `StopIteration` if `'}'` isn't found in `lst`. You can avoid that by doing

```
len(lst) - 1 - next((i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(lst)) if '}' in x), len(lst))
```

and (like Kupiakos's code) it will return -1 if `'}'` isn't found.

---

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name (even in example code) since it shadows the built-in `list` type.

Comment: Why not do `length = len(lst); next((length - i - 1) for i,x in enumerate(reversed(lst)) if '}' in x)`?

Comment: @Kupiakos: Sure, although I'd probably put the arithmetic outside the generator expression. I guess I should add something like that to my answer.

Comment: Not sure if there's any advantage in providing `len(lst)` twice. If the item can't be found, it will be evaluated twice.

Comment: @Kupiakos: Hey, I said your way was more elegant (and I gave you an upvote). :) But `len()` is very fast on Python's built-in container types, since they all keep track of their current length in a simple attribute.

Answer (score 2):

```
def rfind(lst, condition):
    return next((len(lst) - n
                 for (n, i) in enumerate(reversed(lst), 1)
                 if condition(i)),
                -1) # If we couldn't find anything, return -1

>>> lst = ['{b}', '[c]', '{a}', 'g']
>>> print rfind(lst, lambda i: '{' in i)
2
>>> print rfind(lst, lambda i: 'q' in i)
-1
```

Comment: Nice & modular, but it does incur the cost of an extra function call for every item tested.

Comment: @PM2Ring This is true. It depends how often OP is calling it and the level at which speed is preferred above readability.

Comment: Ah! Now I see the merit of putting the arithmetic in the gen exp, since it makes handling the situation where we don't get a match more elegant. :)

Answer (score 0):

Code for finding max index of item in list:

```
mylist = [10, 1, 2, 3, 10, 3]
max_index=max([i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if j==10])
max_index
```

Output: 4

You can see that the index of 10 is at four, python indexes start at zero. Cheers.

Comment: This is probably not as efficient as what the OP would like.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.ifilter()` should be efficient:

```
from itertools import ifilter

def rsearch(lst, condition):
    try:
        return (len(lst) - next(ifilter(lambda t: condition(t[1]),
                                        enumerate(reversed(lst), 1)))[0])
    except StopIteration:
        return None  # nothing satisfied condition

lst = ['{b}', '[c]', '{a}', 'g']

print(rsearch(lst, lambda s: '}' in s))  # -> 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be any more efficient than a generator comprehension. Not to mention that setting up `try` and `except` take unneeded processing.

Comment: @Kupiakos: It's more efficient because `ifilter()` is written in C (see the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a1a1e3fe837a/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c)). Also the overhead for a single `try/except` in Python is minimal.

Comment: Timed in v2.7 and it is pretty slow compared to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be comparable in *time* to a generator expression.

```
a = map(str, xrange(1000000))
a[2000] = 'a'

def f(a):
    for i,n in enumerate(reversed(a)):
        if 'a' in n:
            return len(a) - i - 1
```